# Python .exe unable to find the file but .py is working as expected

Tags: python

I have created a .exe from .py using pyinstaller, .py is working fine but when I execute .exe its not able to find the files. Erroring out at "site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook.

[Screenshot1 for both UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUBd0.png)

[Python Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAz0z.png)

Comment: What is the current working directory when you run it with each method? Hint: `os.getcwd()`